# Find parent key based on child value

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON. I want to know from which country "Jan" is (Belgium).

```
{
    "Belgium": [
        {
            "first_name": "Jan",
            "last_name": "Molenaar"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Piet",
            "last_name": "Hoogenboom"
        }
    ],
    "Germany": [
        {
            "first_name": "Herman",
            "last_name": "Bret"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Sanne",
            "last_name": "Klepper"
        }
    ]
}
```

I found and tried different queries, such as:

```
cat data.json |jq '. as $parent | select(.first_name == "Jan") | $parent'
```

But unfortunately, I am unable to find the correct query.

Comment: if you're interested here another (non-jq) way to achieve the same JSON query: `jtc -w'<Jan>[-2]<>k'`... and greetings from Belgium :) PS. it so happens that Im the developer of `jtc` unix tool

Comment: C-nan - Please clarify what is to be done if there is more than one "Jan" in Belgium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the path to the entry whose `first_name` is `Jan` as an array, and extract the country name from it.

```
path(.[][] | select(.first_name == "Jan"))[0]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/n7_6B4D4Vq)</sup>

Comment: If repetitions are not needed, then enclosing the arg to `path` in a call to `first` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The following prevents the production of repetitions when "Jan" is the first name of several individuals, and is also more efficient than alternatives that unconditionally scan through all "first_name" values:

```
to_entries[] | select( any(.value[]; .first_name=="Jan")).key
```